# Cannot import NodeStyle from vineyard?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

For a machine learning assignment, I wanted the NodeStyle from vineyard. I installed vineyard using command `pip3 install vineyard`  without any error. But still it cannot import NodeStyle from vineyard. But it can import another module (Graph) without problem from vineyard.

```
 File "Jazz.py", line 9, in <module>
    from music_utils import *
  File "/home/bmahakud/deepNeuralNetwork/SequenceModels/music_utils.py", line 8, in <module>
    from grammar import *
  File "/home/bmahakud/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grammar/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .Document import Document, Token
  File "/home/bmahakud/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grammar/Document.py", line 9, in <module>
    from vineyard import Graph, NodeStyle
ImportError: cannot import name 'NodeStyle' from 'vineyard'
```

The exact line that causes above error is
`from vineyard import NodeStyle`

where as the following line does not give any error and works okay.
`from vineyard import Graph`

Comment: Please post the exact import command that causes the error. If there are other relevant commands that execute OK, please post them too.

Comment: added to same post. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can import `graph` because it is part of `vineyard` **But,** `NodeStyle` is not a part of `vineyard`. See this [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/vineyard/).

`NodeStyle` is belongs to `ete2` library. Check this [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/ete2/).

Therefore, final outcome should be like this.

- `pip install ete2`
- `from ete2 import NodeStyle`